# Strict Regular Expression String Comparison in Bash Script

Tags: regex, bash, registry

I'm attempting to write a simple Bash script that will help me verify some Windows registry settings. All the data is within folders (which is the computer's hostname), and at the path stated in the script. The end goal is to verify the hosts that have the value incorrectly set, based on registry key value at the end of the line.

For reference of the script, parameter one is the registry key I would like to look for, parameter two is the value it should be. If `$control` matches what is on the end of `$value`'s string then it should output the machine name which is the variable `$FOLDER`

```
list=$(ls)
regkey=$1
control=$2

for FOLDER in $list
do
value=$($FOLDER/policies/Effective-Security-policy.txt | grep "$regkey")
if [[ "$value" =~ $control ]] ;
    then
        echo $FOLDER
    else
        continue
fi  
done
```

However, I can't get it to do a strict compare, because there is also a registry key named `RestrictAnonymousSAM` and it will list out values that are incorrect.

Here are some of the lines from within the text file, I need to be able to differentiate between the two, so the returned values are for that particular registry key:

```
MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\RestrictAnonymous=4,0
MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\RestrictAnonymousSAM=4,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, I think you should write:

```
regkey="$1"
control="$2"

for FOLDER in * ; do
  file="$FOLDER/policies/Effective-Security-policy.txt"
  if iconv -s -f utf-16 -t utf-8 "$file" \
       | grep -q '^[^=]*\\'"$regkey=$control$"
  then
    echo "$FOLDER"
  fi    
done
```

`grep -q` searches the file for lines matching the pattern, but does *not* print them out. This makes it well-suited to use in `if`-tests, since `grep` returns `0` (success/true) if it finds a match and `1` (error/false) if it does not.

(Important note: the above assumes that `$regkey` and `$control` can't contain any metacharacters that `grep` might treat specially. If they *can*, then this becomes trickier.)

Comment: You are correct, there should not be any metacharacters passed through the grep. However, I did leave one part out, because I thought I would be able add it in once I had some help. In order for grep to parse the results I have had to use `value=$(iconv -s -f utf-16 -t utf-8 $FOLDER/policies/Effective-Security-policy.txt` adding that in for _$file_ outputs the entire text document in the echo.

Comment: @0mgz: That's fine; you can put any command you want, or even a sequence of commands, between the `if` and the `then`. I've updated my answer to have `grep` take its input from the output of `iconv`.

Comment: I am still unable to get it working. It is grabbing the path correctly (verified that), but when the script runs, no output is displayed. If grep returns 0 or 1, do I need to pass _$2_ a 0 or 1. I was looking to be able to pass variations of registry values such as "4,1" "4,0" "4,3" etc... appreciate the help so far.

Comment: @0mgz: When I say that a command "returns" `0` or `1`, I mean that that's its exit status -- that's the value that `if` is checking for. You still want `$control` to be what it was before, e.g. `4,1`, because that's goes inside the `grep` command. To test if the `grep` is working properly, try running `iconv -s -f utf-16 -t utf-8 "$file" | grep '^[^=]*\\'"$regkey=$control$"` (without `-q`) and seeing what it prints out.

Comment: When that `grep` command is used in the script without the `-q` the results are the same. No output. However, I ran the statement straight from the command line and there is output. When using `iconv -s -f utf-16 -t utf-8 Effective-Security-policy.txt | grep '^[^=]*\\'"RestrictAnonymous"` the output is `MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\RestrictAnonymous=4,0
MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\RestrictAnonymousSAM=4,1`

Comment: @0mgz: Oh. Hmm. So it's O.K. with everything up through `$regkey`, but then it doesn't like the `=$control$`? I wonder if it's because of Windows, if there's a stray carriage-return or something. What happens if you change the `=$control$"` to `=$control[[:space:]]*$"`?

Comment: That appears to have fixed it. Verified the results with the files I have. @ruakh I appreciate you taking the time to help me understand. Thanks!